# Is that possible to have two namespaces in the class XMLTypeAttribute to handle deserialization of 2 soap responses?

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I have a class that has the following declaration:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]

public partial class Envelope
{
    private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public EnvelopeBody Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }
}

.
. another code generated here based on response XML...
.

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "order")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "order", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class insertResponse
{

    private insertResponseOut outField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public insertResponseOut @out
    {
        get
        {
            return this.outField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.outField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When deserializing `XML` response containing `<insertResponse xmlns="order">`, I can successfully do that.

I have another XML SOAP response, that is exactly of the same format and I want to use the same class, but with the different `XmlTypeAttribute`:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "customer")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "customer", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class insertResponse
{

    private insertResponseOut outField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public insertResponseOut @out
    {
        get
        {
            return this.outField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.outField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have a method handling deserialization of SOAP response:

```
private Envelope DeserializeSoapResponse<T>(string soapResponse)
{
     var serealizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
     Envelope result;

     using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(soapResponse))
     {
         result = (Envelope)serealizer.Deserialize(reader);
     }

     return result;
 }
```

soapResponse parameter is not the path to the XML, it is a string representing xml SOAP response from the server.

I also, tried to use custom xml reader:

```
public class CustomXmlReader: System.Xml.XmlTextReader
{
    public CustomXmlReader(string url) : base(url) { }

    public override string NamespaceURI
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.NamespaceURI == "order")
                return "customer";

            return base.NamespaceURI;
        }
    }
}
```

as was suggested, but I have the following error: `illegal character in path`, since, as I expect, I need to send the URL to the SOAP response, but sending the string

How can I do something like that? Is that possible to define multiple namespaces for `XmlTypeAttribute` or `XmlRootAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use the custom xml reader.

```
public class CustomXmlReader : XmlTextReader
{
    // Define other required constructors
    public CustomXmlReader(string url) : base(url) { }
    public CustomXmlReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

    public override string NamespaceURI
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.NamespaceURI == "order")
                return "customer";

            return base.NamespaceURI;
        }
    }
}
```

It converts an `order` namespace to a `customer` namespace on the fly.

Accordingly, your class should have only one `customer` namespase declaration:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "customer")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "customer", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class insertResponse
```

Use as usual:

```
string xml = "your xml here";

insertResponse response;

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
using (var xmlReader = new CustomXmlReader(stringReader))
    response = (insertResponse)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

Comment: I tried to use this approach, but have an exception saying that `illegal character in the path`. I think it is caused by sending string representing XML SOAP response instead of path itself. But that logic works for "order" deserialization

Comment: @gene - I wrote: define the other necessary [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)! See update.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested, but still have the same error